# Сохранение данных DataGrid'а в XML-файл(сериализация) после закрытия формы

Tags: c#, winforms, xml, сериализация

Чтобы не описывать долго что у меня есть в программе и суть задания, прикреплю скриншот самого задания для лучшего понимания[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так вот, как мне загрузить данные с DataGrid'ов в XML-файлы после закрытия формы и наоборот, чтобы данные подгружались в таблицы после запуска программы? Гриды и заполнение их происходит через DataBinding

Comment: Через data-binding значит есть объект-модель. Для него, например, например, [эти два метода](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14663848/2772330) могут пригодиться - то что сходу нашлось. Первый позволяет сохранить себя объекту (this), второй восстановить. Оба должны быть методами объекта с данными. Второй - статический. Еще: лучше так не вывешивать фото задачек, лучше просто описать ту часть, касающуюся сериализации, а поскольку она уже есть, то найти существующий ответ.

Comment: спасибо, я выложил фото чтобы не писать сто строк про суть задания и прочее, понял, еще раз спасибо за ответ)

Comment: и еще, данные методы мы вызываем в событиях Forn_Closed и Form_OnLoad ?

Comment: думаю, что можно так.  Если что, то можно [обсудить немного в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97680/erleug-try-course-work--), но не  готов этим долго заниматься. Если только вопросы точечные, то может быть получится поотвечать, хотя не обещаю. Но можно вопросы и на основном сайте спросить, если уместно.

Comment: не могу писать в чате( может не туда смотрю

Comment: писать в чате могут не все участники (только с репутацией выше 20). Поэтому, теоретически можно тебе оформить ответ про сериализацию, тогда могу поставить upvote= +10 тогда останется еще копейки набрать как-нибудь (например, второй ответ написать со вторым подходом, потом), тогда можно будет писать. Если чего-то не упустил в своей логике...

Comment: понял, спасибо, может наберу